# Do I need to check for inequality between old and new values in watchers?

Tags: vue.js

Currently, a lot of my watcher code looks like this:

```
watch: {
  // whenever question changes, this function will run
  question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
    if (newQuestion != oldQuestion) {
       // do something
    }
  }
},
```

My question is if I need `newQuestion != oldQuestion` or does Vue not trigger the watcher if `newQuestion = oldQuestion`. If the latter is true, then what kind of inequalities does Vue check for? Just `=` or deep equality (e.g. all checking if elements of array are same even if arrays aren't the same) as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the watcher does not trigger if they are equal. To check for deep equal you could structure your watcher like so (only needed when dealing with non scalars).

```
question: {
   handler: () => {},
   deep: true
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Official documentation for this feature is on https://vuejs.org/v2/api/, ctrl+f `deep: true`

Answer (score 0):

try it yourself:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:_=>({x:"", log:""}),
  watch:{
    x(nw,od){
      this.log += `<hr/>old: ${od} new: ${nw} x: ${this.x}`
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="x"/>
  <div v-html="log"></div> 
</div>
```